# Is it possible to pass a query string in the URL to a durable function?

Tags: azure, azure-durable-functions

Is it possible to pass a query string in the URL through GET request to Azure durable function? For example:

`http://localhost:7071/api/orchestrators/{functionName}?id=1`

If so, how do I access it in JavaScript? `context.df.getInput()` doesn't seem to collect query strings.

From what I gathered, it's only possible to pass data via POST requests.

Comment: [Create your first durable function in JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-js-vscode#:~:text=Copy%20the%20URL%20value%20for%20statusQueryGetUri%20and%20paste%20it%20in%20the%20browser%27s%20address%20bar%20and%20execute%20the%20request.%20Alternatively%20you%20can%20also%20continue%20to%20use%20Postman%20to%20issue%20the%20GET%20request.) and [context.df.callHttp POST calls body not recognized](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-js/issues/349)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT I can use durable functions with POST request, no problem. My question was whether it's possible to pass data to the orchestrator using GET request and a query string, e.g. `?id=1`.